# Adding another shortcut to File Manager

Tags: 16.10, shortcuts, filemanager

By default the file manager has several links in the left column:

- Recent
- Home
- Desktop
- Documents
- Downloads
- Music
- Pictures
- Videos
- Trash

Can I make an option for 'Programming' in that list?  What steps would I need to do?

I specifically want to draw attention to the fact that I am using Ubuntu 16.10.  The link challenging this as a 'duplicate' question was for an older version of Ubuntu.  I am asking for instructions specific to Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Ron, did you read the duplicate? The question itself has your answer: Press Ctrl+D while inside the folder, or drag the folder to the sidebar, or use the Bookmarks menu in the menu bar.

Comment: I did look.  With Linux being highly customizable I wanted to ensure I was  executing correct commands.  I am undergoing intensive treatment for a long term physical disability.  If I mess my Ubuntu up I would be cutting myself off from how heavily I rely on the Internet to shop and manage the effects of this.  In short I felt it was prudent to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @RonPiggott Configuring Nautilus isn't likely to mess anything up, but point taken. BTW, if you do mess up Ubuntu, it could be useful to have an Ubuntu live USB/CD available, and maybe an external HDD too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for various file managers, across different Ubuntu versions and even on other distros.

Locate and edit the GTK bookmarks file (for Ubuntu 16.10 it is located at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`) and add to it:

```
file:///path/to/programming_dir Programming
```

By the way, you can use a one liner:

```
echo "file:///path/to/programming_dir Programming" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

For remote dirs, you can use other URI schemas, like `smb://`.